# Django - saving fields in invalid form submissions

Tags: python, django, django-forms

What is the recommended way of handling a "save"-style form submission (created from a ModelForm) when:

1. A non-empty subset of the form's fields validate
2. A non-empty subset of the form's fields do not validate
3. I want to save the subset of fields that *are* valid to the instance in question, and *not* the invalid ones.

I'm fairly sure I could write the code to do this but as with much of Django I'm sure there's a "normal"/"recommended" way of solving this, or some pattern I can follow.

All advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to provide your own `clean` method to deal with the non-validating fields, and prevent cleaned_data being clobbered.

You will need to also provide your own `save` method which knows to only save the right fields.